# Insert p element into a div element using PHP

Tags: php, html, insert

Currently, I use PHP code to echo SQL data that is flagged as not yet being displayed into a div element.
I do this by looping through a database table and checking that a particular column value is either '0' or '1' -- if the value is '0', I echo it into the html div, and update the database with a value of '1'.

That being said, I am only ever displaying one piece of data, because it clears everything that was already in the div element.

Is there a way to echo the new data, without clearing the pre-existing insertions?

Here is how I'm calling the .php file:

```
$.post("chat_process.php", {message: $("#message").val(), user_update: "true"},  
        function(data) { $("#rect_comments_text").html(data); $("#message").val(""); }  );
```

The div element that is being updated is #rect_comments_text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `$("#rect_comments_text").append(data)`